# Want to add multiple column into Magento 2 admin panel left side menu

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add multiple column into Magento 2 admin custom module. I have added screen shot for more details. Which explain what I am looking for.

Please share your ideas and help.

[image]

Comment: please check this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add menu.xml to your custom module app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::menu1" title="Menu 1" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="120" parent="Magento_Reports::report" resource="Vendor_Module::menu1"/>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::test1" title="Test 1" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="10" parent="Vendor_Module::menu1" action="route/controller/action" resource="Vendor_Module::test1"/>

        <add id="Vendor_Module::menu2" title="Menu 2" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="130" parent="Magento_Reports::report" resource="Vendor_Module::menu2"/>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::test2" title="Test 2" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="10" parent="Vendor_Module::menu2" action="route/controller/action" resource="Vendor_Module::test2"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

this will be add menu in Reports you can change parent by your need replace with it **"Magento_Reports::report"**

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check and get back..

Comment: It works, Thanks!